# Cannot deduce type of const after explicit type check? (TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.)

Tags: typescript

I've run into a bizarre issue with TypeScript where it seems like I should be able to deduce that a constant is an array, and with that knowledge call array methods on it. However, TypeScript apparently isn't able to determine that a value is truly an array even after an explicit check.

Given:

```
type Maybe<T> = T | null | undefined;

type Value = string
  | number
  | string[]
  | number[]
  | Maybe<number | string>[];
```

I can call the `.every` array method on a constant if I typecheck the constant thusly:

```
// This approach works fine:
const currVal: Maybe<Value> = perhapsSomeValueSomewhere;

if (Array.isArray(currVal)) {
  const arr: any[] = currVal;
  const isListOfStrings = arr.every((s) => typeof(s) === 'string');

  // ... Do other stuff here
}
```

I feel like it should follow that the above can be reduced to:

```
// This approach results in an error:
const currVal: Maybe<Value> = perhapsSomeValueSomewhere;
const isListOfStrings = Array.isArray(currVal)
  && currVal.every((s) => typeof(s) === 'string');

// ... Do other stuff here
```

However this approach results in an error:

```
TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((callbackfn: (value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => boolean, thisArg?: any) => boole...' has no compatible call signatures.
```

I can only assume this means that, along the way, TypeScript has lost the context that by `&& currVal.every((s) => ...` this point, `currVal` is indeed an array of some sort.

Why would the latter result in an error when the two bits of logic seem rather comparable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you have an implicit type cast by assigning currVal to any[], in the second you have not cast the type to an array type. You can get this to work with the following explicit cast.

```
const isListOfStrings = Array.isArray(currVal) && (<Array<any>>currVal).every((s) => typeof (s) === 'string');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response -- Is there a difference between asserting the constant as `arr: any[]` and strictly _casting_ it which is what I think we're doing in your example: `<Array<any>>currVal`.

I was under the impression the former grants some compile-time safety while the latter does not?

Comment: I have tidied up the terminology in the answer, when you assign to any[] there is an implicit cast that takes place, the compiler will warn if the assignment is known to be invalid, when you do an explicit cast the compiler will also warn if it is invalid. The potential problem with your code sample is that it will not necessarily be known in advance  what type Value will have so the compiler will not warn. In both instances of your sample you are protected at runtime by the Array.isArray call since the && operator only evaluates the second expression when first is true.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!